# Display fallback theme directory image outputs url and not the image

Tags: php, wordpress, function, if-statement

I am adding a custom admin table column for my post thumbnails in WordPress.

Wanting to retrieve a fallback image from my theme image directory if no post thumbnail has been created, and to use php without wrapping in html img tags.

So I thought I could do `echo get_template_directory_uri() .'/assets/images/geo.jpg';` however that is only displaying the url.

What am I missing?

Code:

```
...

function cpt_columns_content($column_id, $post_id) {
    if ($column_id == 'last_modified') {
        echo get_post_field('post_modified', $post_id);
    } 
    else if ('post_thumbs') {
        if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
            // get the post featured thumbnail
            the_post_thumbnail('xsm_thumbnail');
        } 
        else {
            // or else get from theme image directory
            echo get_template_directory_uri() .'/assets/images/geo.jpg';
        }
    }
}
add_action('manage_program_posts_custom_column', 'cpt_columns_content', 10, 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

the_post_thumbnail() return full img tag html. You must print  tag as well , like this code :

```
function cpt_columns_content($column_id, $post_id) {
    if ($column_id == 'last_modified') {
      echo get_post_field('post_modified', $post_id);
    }
    else if ('post_thumbs') {
     if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
        // get the post featured thumbnail
        the_post_thumbnail('xsm_thumbnail');
    }
    else {
        // or else get from theme image directory
        echo sprintf('<img src="%s" width="70px" height="70px" />', 
                get_template_directory_uri() .'/assets/images/geo.jpg');
    }
   }
 }
add_action('manage_program_posts_custom_column', 'cpt_columns_content', 10, 2);
```

Comment: Siavash so theres no way of outputting just php? I don't want the html tags

Comment: @Krys No Unfortunately, in this hook you only have to print the output, which must include the tag.

Comment: Siavash can I use the `xsm_thumbnail` from add_image_sizes instead of hardcoding the html width and height attributes?

Comment: @Krys Yes my code is for test ... you can get and replace width and height attributes from any source. just replace their value with %s and pass their value to sprintf parameters.

Comment: Replace $width_value and $height_value with their actual values. echo sprintf('<img src="%s" width="%s" height="%s" />', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/images/geo.jpg', $width_value, $height_value);

Comment: echo sprintf('<img src="%s" width="%s" height="%s" />', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/images/geo.jpg' ,  "60px", "60px");

Comment: okay, got you now.